# get all html element object with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

is there any jQuery function that return a list of all HTML element of a given page?
I need this in order to do the following test:

If an element has a given class do something, for all the HTML elements on my page

Comment: Just select the elements that have the class, surely...

Comment: i don't know why this discussion has been closed i was waiting the eight hours in order to post my answer to help people who are seeking the same thing that's my code  '$('*').each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("class").indexOf("aString")!= -1)
      {//do something}
       });
       });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples:

```
// for all elements
$('*');

// for all elements with a class test
$('.test');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.classYouAreSearchingFor')` is the selector you want.

You'll get an array of matched items back.  You can iterate through them.

Given this HTML:

```
​<ul>
  <li class='item'>Hi</li>
  <li class='item'>Hello</li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

you can iterate over each matched HTML that has the `item` class:

```
$('.item').each(function(i, item) { alert($(this).text());});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [class as the selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). This will be much faster than cycling through all elements on the page, as this will use the native API to find the matched elements.

If you wanted to add another class to every element that has `.foo` to begin with:

```
/* if an element has a given class do something */
$(".foo").addClass("bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div,span {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="notMe">div class="notMe"</div>

  <div class="myClass">div class="myClass"</div>
  <span class="myClass">span class="myClass"</span>
<script>$(".myClass").css("border","3px solid red");</script>

</body>
</html>
```